# OAuth 2.0 implicit flow working for localhost but not when site deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service, onedrive

I have modified sample code that connects to OneDrive and allows user to upload/download images to OneDrive. I have deployed MVC5 app [here](http://onedriveuploaddemo.azurewebsites.net/). Below is key piece of javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var client_id = "61029bc2-373d-46d6-935b-ab34b325ef3a",
                scope = ["wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update"],
                //redirect_uri = "http://localhost:61727/home/callback";  //when redirect_uri is configured as localhost everything works find
                  redirect_uri = "http://onedriveuploaddemo.azurewebsites.net/home/callback"; //When I deploy application to azure get error saying invalid redirect_uri

            WL.Event.subscribe("auth.login", onLogin);
            WL.Event.subscribe("auth.sessionChange", onSessionChange);
            WL.init({ client_id: client_id, redirect_uri: redirect_uri, response_type: "token", scope: scope });
            WL.ui({ name: "signin", element: "signin" });

        });
```

Please see below configuration of app

[image]

1. When I configure 'redirect_uri' as local host i.e. (*http://localhost:61727/home/callback*).  Application works as expected.  When I click on login button it redirect me to windows live login screen, then I can enter my username/password and I am redirected back to 'redirect_url'
2. But trouble starts when I change 'redirect_uri' that is pointing to page thats  hosted in azure.  I have hosted the MVC app [here](http://onedriveuploaddemo.azurewebsites.net/) .  When I click on 'SignIn' button it opens up dialog and closes it immediately.  I am not able to grab error message.  But it seems to be an issue with  'redirect_uri'

> Do I need to enable any setting in Azure in order to get this done?

**Note:** While configuring 'redirect_uri' I am changing it at both the places i.e. in MVC app and in 'Application Registration Portal' and both are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Fiddler4, I was able to catch the error message, which is:
`The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The scope 'wl.signin wl.basic wl.skydrive wl.skydrive_update' requires that the request must be sent over a secure connection using SSL.`

Microsoft now requires that the redirect URI use SSL for all authentication redirects. Localhost is exempt, which is why it worked there. If you want to allow login using Microsoft Account, you need to have SSL support on your site.

Also: it looks like you are using the very old LiveSDK for JavaScript, which isn't recommended any more since it doesn't support the newer OneDrive API. While there isn't a OneDrive SDK for JavaScript, you may find the sample code in [OneDrive-Explorer-JS](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-js) helpful to handle authentication without using the LiveSDK code. In particular, [odauth.js](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-js/blob/master/odauth.js) should do pretty much everything you need.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Gregg I used secure connection and now I can access OneDrive.  Also thanks for letting me know about latest  technology to access OneDrive.

Comment: @RyanGregg Could you post a link to Microsoft documentation regarding requirement to use only SSL for redirect URI? I can not find it.